# In express, how to get the attribute name from form when it has dash?

Tags: node.js, express

Due to some reasons for compatibility with other apps, I need to use the dash and trying to figure out how to get the field name when it has a dash

```
<input type="text" name="batch-code">
```

I have added the body-parser in app but don't seem to find the way to get that value with a dash.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Is there any way that I can retrive that?

TA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access using `[]` notation. `req.body['batch-code']`, make sure your form's `enctype` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default) and not `multipart/form-data`

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/form', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body['batch-code']);
   res.json(req.body);
});
```

```html
<form action="/form" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="batch-code">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you I was trying to get that with the `.` added too like this.  `req.body.['batch-code']`